# SQL Query Payments due after threshold met

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

We payout commission to sales agents for fees collected from clients, but only after a threshold has been met. In my example, the threshold for this client is $3,166.09 and as we collect fees, they've met the threshold by the 8/12/2021 transaction and gone over a bit when you look at the cumulative total amount of fees collected to that point. I'm just getting hung up on how to calculate that last column of "COMMISSION_PMT"

DESIRED RESULTS:

| CUST_ID | PMT_DATE | THRESHOLD | FEE_COLLECTED | RUNNING_TTL | COMMISSION_PMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110 | 2021-04-28 | 3166.09 | 764.25 | 764.25 | 0 |
| 110 | 2021-05-11 | 3166.09 | 449.75 | 1214 | 0 |
| 110 | 2021-07-27 | 3166.09 | 1709 | 2923 | 0 |
| 110 | 2021-08-12 | 3166.09 | 910.5 | 3833.5 | 667.41 |
| 110 | 2021-08-31 | 3166.09 | 164.91 | 3998.41 | 164.91 |
| 110 | 2021-09-27 | 3166.09 | 594.75 | 4593.16 | 594.75 |
| 110 | 2021-10-01 | 3166.09 | 1343.25 | 5936.41 | 1343.25 |

```
select
t.cust_id
, t.pmt_date
, c.threshold
, sum(t.fee_collected) over(partition by t.cust_id order by t.pmt_date asc) as running_ttl
, case
    when sum(t.fee_collected) over(partition by t.cust_id order by t.pmt_date asc) < c.threshold
    then 0
    else t.fee_collected
 end as commission_pmt
```

from transactions t
inner join customers c on t.cust_id = c.id
order by 2 asc

Comment: Hi Serena, what did you try so far? What is not workin? Do you have a sample query, that you tried out to compute the column? Then someone might be able to find the error and help you.

Comment: Can you please add the query you tried to the question also?

Comment: I have created a real out of it: https://replit.com/@rasenderhase/SQL-Query-Payments-due-after-threshold-met?v=1
As I understood payments should not continue after 1st payment, but wait until threshold is again met...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I got it:

```
select t.cust_id, t.pmt_date, t.threshold, t.fee_collected,
  case when t.part_row_number = t.max_part_row_number and t.temp_cash > t.threshold then t.temp_cash else 0 end commission_pmt
from (
  select t.*,
    max(part_row_number) over(partition by t.cust_id, t.part) max_part_row_number
  from (
    select t.*,
      row_number() over(partition by t.cust_id, t.part) part_row_number,
      sum(t.fee_collected) over(partition by t.cust_id, t.part) temp_cash
    from (
      select t.*, 
        floor((t.ttl - t.fee_collected) / t.threshold) part
      from (
        select t.*,
          sum(t.fee_collected) over(partition by t.cust_id order by t.pmt_date) ttl
        from payments t
      ) t
    ) t
  )t
)t;
```

yields:

```
110|2021-04-28|3166.09|  764.25|0
110|2021-05-11|3166.09|  449.75|0
110|2021-07-27|3166.09| 1709.00|0
110|2021-08-12|3166.09|  910.50|3833.5
110|2021-08-31|3166.09|  164.91|0
110|2021-09-27|3166.09|  594.75|0
110|2021-10-01|3166.09| 1343.25|0
```

1. `ttl`: the collected fees are summed up per customer over the dates.
2. `part`: the partition is created for each threshold area.
3. `part_row_number`: row number inside each partition and `temp_cash`, the summed up collected fee in each partition `part`.
4. `max_part_row_number` of each partition `part`.
5. `commission_pmt` is each row with `max_part_row_number`... if it's greater than threshold.

You can test it here: https://replit.com/@rasenderhase/SQL-Query-Payments-due-after-threshold-met?v=1

Cheers.

Comment: Hint: I would copy the current threshold into the transactions table for each transaction inserted. So if you change the threshold for a certain customer it does not change past `commission_pmt` values.